# WMS GetMap request failed on secured endpoint with basic header authentication?

Tags: qgis, wms, authentication

I've tried to connect QGIS version 2 and 3 with a WMS service endpoint protected with basic authentication.

The strange thing is, it can send WMS GetCapabilities without problem (with username and password given in the QIGS WMS login form).

[image]

[image]

However, it failed to send WMS GetMap with the given credentials. What is wrong here?

```
2022-09-26T11:00:59 1   Map request failed [error:Host requires authentication url:https://REMOVED_ENDPOINT/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=16.92450000000000188,-41.97400000000000375,71.8995000000000033,55.71099999999999852&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1156&HEIGHT=650&LAYERS=mundi.earthserver.xyz:7000:EU_DEM&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE]
```

Comment: does the request work when you send it outside of QGIS

Comment: @nmtoken yes it works outside of QGIS. The issue is from how QGIS parses WMS GetCapabilities to get the URL for GetMap requests.

Comment: So the password over http doesn't work, but it does over https?   if so that's a server error, not QGIS.

Comment: @nmtoken yes as you said, I fixed that in the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from how QGIS parses WMS GetCapabilities result to get the URL for GetMap requests.

In the WMS GetCapabilities result, it is configured as http, not https (proxied by apache), hence, QGIS had the issue.

Comment: If the url is wrong in the GetCapabilities you can use a check box in QGIS to ignore it